# How to add ng-swipe-left and ng-swipe-right for angularUI datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-touch

How to add ng-swipe-left and ng-swipe-right using angular-touch library to navigate angularUI datepicker next & previous months ?

I added the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLjO4W4L2icscHdIfwAA?p=preview)

```
    $scope.Next = function() {
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
      angular.element(document.querySelector('.pull-right')).triggerHandler('click');
    });
  };

  $scope.Previous = function() {
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
      angular.element(document.querySelector('.pull-right')).triggerHandler('click');
    });
  };
```

From the plunker code , I am getting **Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress** from browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Used $timeout service.working good.

```
        $scope.Next = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.pull-right')[0]).triggerHandler('click');
            });
        };

        $scope.Previous = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.pull-left')[0]).triggerHandler('click');
            });
        };
```